# Orthographic camera and z-axis in 3D isometric view game

Tags: camera, isometric

I'm working  on a game in Away3d. I'm using an orthographic camera and I'm attempting to simulate an isometric view (the camera has a 37° angle and the y-axis is up/down, x-axis is left/right, and z-axis is orthographic).

I hit a snag in understanding how to handle the z-axis of the NPC's relative to the player so that, for example, when the player is below an NPC in Y coordinates, it doesn't appear to be "under" the NPC, but "besides/in front" the NPC, as currently all the 3D models in this scene are Z-axis coordinate 0.

My common sense says that there should be a relation in the sense that if the Y axis coordinates of the NPC is lower than the Y axis coordinates of the player, then the z-axis coordinates should update following an allegory is so that the apparent view of the NPC relative to the player is that the NPC is "behind" the player. But as I said, because all the z-axis are zero for all the models, the players' apparent position is "under" the NPC, as opposed to "in front" of the NPC.

Comment: has been asked several times in some variations: probably one of these:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8151/how-should-i-sort-images-in-an-isometric-game-so-that-they-appear-in-the-correct?lq=1
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25982/how-do-i-determine-the-draw-order-in-an-isometric-view-flash-game?rq=1
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49226/3d-isometric-depth-sorting
etc.

You need some data about the depth of your objects and then should draw them using the painters algorithm.

Comment: I think I figured it out, so I mention it here for future reference, if anyone needs it. In my case I needed to project 1 Pixel in  2-D y-axis( up-and-down in my case), with its equivalent in 3-D y-axis and z-axis( To simulate depth).. So basically 1 pixel in  2-D projection is  3-D  one pixel in y-axis multiplied with  sine  of camera angle, and 3-D one pixel in z-axis multiplied with  cosine of camera angle.
 something like this: 3-D position is equal with vector 3-D(x,y * sin( angle),y * cos( angle))