# Isometric projection bad coordonate

Tags: isometric, andengine

I have a 2D map, for each element I apply this isometric projection to place my Sprite

```
 //Element e;
 float[] f= projection(e.getX(), e.getY() ,z);
         // x and y represent Sprite Coordonate (tile_width and height depend of my 
         // camera size and the number of elements in x and in y
 float x =  f[0]*tile_width;
 float y =  f[1]*tile_height;
```

---

```
   public float[] projection(float x, float y, float z)
   {
     return new float[]{  (( x )-(y) ) , ((x/2) + (y/2) - z  )}; 
   }
```

the sprite for one element :

[image]

The result of my projection :

[image]

---

The problem is I need to add an offset of tile_height/2 to the y and tile_width/2 to the x to have something like this (in the red rectangle I drawed with paint what I want) :

[image]

**Where did I make wrong?**

(I found the projection method in [How should I sort images in an isometric game so that they appear in the correct order?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8151/how-should-i-sort-images-in-an-isometric-game-so-that-they-appear-in-the-correct) )

**edit :  How I calculate my tile_height and tile_width :**

```
    tile_height = (float) ((CAMERA_HEIGHT/(game.map.getHeight()/2)));
    tile_width =  (float) ((CAMERA_HEIGHT/(game.map.getWidth()/2)));
```

Comment: I haven't done isometric projection before, but shouldn't the tile_height and tile_width be the height and width of the tile sprite?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to create a single projection for multiplying with width and height, but I believe if you send the height and width along,  the Projection would be:

```
public float[] projection(float x, float y, float z, float width, float height)
{
  return new float[]{  
    (x * width / 2) + (y * width / 2),
    (y * height / 2) - (x * height / 2) - (z*height)
  }; 
}
```

Maybe have a look at 1ManBandStudios' post [here](http://goo.gl/dVSuh).

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I notice an interesting difference in the calculations here.  Your code calculates the projection as [x+y, y-x-z] where the code in the question uses [x-y, x+y-z]

Comment: That doesn't matter - it just changes the orientation (which direction is x/y).

Comment: It doesn't work